# UIImagepicker display Image capturing instead of Video recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

I am using UIImagepickerController to capture video in my app.
Sometimes it behaves strangely - that image capturing is coming. Mostly it comes when a new user is registered and try to capture a video or a new ipa file is installed and tested. Eventhough it appears randomly.

When I prompt UIImagepickerController it display take photo button (White button) instead of video record button (Red button)

Here is my code -

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
 imagePicker.delegate=self;
 if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
   {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
  }
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Both take image and video is coming or sometimes only take image (no video option) is coming ?

Comment: Sometimes only take image option is coming, just take image button is there.

Comment: Use this "imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];" you will get both options all the time.

Comment: I dont want both option, this is built only to take videos.

Answer (score 1):

Just try replacing your code with this.

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
   // picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMoviekUTTypeImage];
    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,nil];
    //picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```